Could Not Find Required Gems for Rails Project - bundle install Missing Multiple Gems
I’m trying to set up a Rails project, but I keep encountering issues with missing gems, even after running bundle install. The specific error message I’m seeing is:
Could not find propshaft-1.1.0, importmap-rails-2.0.3, turbo-rails-2.0.11, stimulus-rails-1.3.4, solid_cache-1.0.6, solid_queue-1.0.1, solid_cable-3.0.2, web-console-4.2.1, irb-1.14.1, rdoc-6.7.0, psych-5.2.0 in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install --gemfile C:/Users/MJ/Desktop/myapp/Gemfile` to install missing gems.

Problem Introduction
I encountered this issue while trying to set up a new Rails project on Windows 11. Despite having run bundle install multiple times, the project still reports that it can’t find several required gems. I’ve verified that these gems are listed in my Gemfile, so I’m unsure why bundle install isn’t resolving the issue.
What I Tried and Expected

Ran bundle install: Expected all gems to be installed successfully, but the error persisted.
Checked the Gemfile: Confirmed all missing gems were listed correctly.
Ran bundle update: Expected this might help install or update missing dependencies, but it didn’t resolve the problem.

Environment Details

Ruby version: 3.3.6 (x64-mingw-ucrt)
Rails version: 8.0.0
Node.js version: v22.11.0
Yarn version: 1.22.22
Operating System: Windows 11

Question
What might be causing bundle install to fail to install these gems, and is this a compatibility issue with Rails 8.0.0, Ruby 3.3.6, or Windows? Any additional configuration steps would be appreciated.

What command (for example, rails server) do you run that returns the error message about missing gems? Do you run the command prefixed with bundle exec (like bundle exec rails server)? Are the gems in question listed when you run gem list in the project folder?

yes i tried all

Could you post your Gemfile?

Sometimes organization's network can block bundle install's web request. So be sure for your internet connection is not filtered or blocked by antivirus or firewall etc.

After rails new bundle install could be broken if you don't have any installed bundler version.
Remove the created directory and try gem install bundler first then run your rails new command again.
